# Using A Web Service .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have created a Web Service to query Solr in C# Using Microsoft Visual Studio and I can test it is working by running it on the local server that comes standard with MSVS.  That is all fine.

I now want to integrate that into a web page which I havent created yet.  I need a text box to input the search terms (since Solr is my search engine) and a way of parsing the xml response to display what I want.

I have very little experience with .net so need some pointers to where to look next

Comment: Do you want steps to integrate that webservice with your webapplication.

Comment: there are many ways to parse XML data returned from a web service one way depending on what information you are returning from the web service would be to use or create a DataSet and it's XML internal functionality to retrieve the xml values that you need

Comment: Add service reference and paste your url.it will integrate your webservice.then create an instance of the service reference and create object for it.then using that object call the webmethod.then if the web method returns xml data convert it into html using xslt and display it in your webp[age..

Comment: I appreciate the comments, any links or guides that might be helpful for your suggestions